# Stuck with two prepositions -You can come from/on Monday on!

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I got stuck while writing a mail to my students in which I am saying that they should resume their classes from Tuesday on.

> I'm out of town on Monday. You can come *from/on* Tuesday on.

We use *from* to start a point of 'onward.' `From 6 p.m. on` which means it starts at 6 p.m. and then it'll go on.

I also know that we have 'on' for days - on Monday/Tuesday... and so on. Grammarly corrected my sentence and said 'on.' But how would it look then?

> You can come *on Tuesday on!*

Comment: _You can come from Tuesday onwards_

Comment: *On* sounds odd at the end of the sentence. It can be omitted completely or replaced as suggested above. But often, one can simply rephrase to avoid any confusion, as in: Classes will resume on Tuesday.

Comment: One writes mail, or a letter, or email, or an email, but "writing a mail" is an unusual usage. Compare [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=write+mail%2C+write+email%2C+write+a+mail%2C+write+an+email%2C+write+a+letter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrite%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20a%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20an%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20a%20letter%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...with [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=write+mail%2Cwrite+email%2Cwrite+a+mail%2Cwrite+an+email&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrite%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20a%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20an%20email%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Classes will resume on Tuesday*.   There's no need for the "on" or "onward", since **resume** means to get back to the normal or usual schedule.